View is emtpy after onAppear call to firebase firestore after button click (From another view)
I am trying to populate a view when a button is tapped on a different view. When I used my mock data, everything worked fine. However, when I switch to calling my firestore db data, nothing shows up. I'm still a few months into learning swiftui but I called on db the same way in a different part of my project which worked well. Here is an example of the code I am using.
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct RewardsView: View {
    
// Dummy Data
//    var rewardItems: [Reward] = [
//        .init(RewardText: "10% Off Next Haircut", RewardRedeemed: false, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 10),
//        .init(RewardText: "10% Off Extra Service", RewardRedeemed: true, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 8),
//        .init(RewardText: "20% Next Haircut", RewardRedeemed: false, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 15),
//        .init(RewardText: "30% off Next Haircut", RewardRedeemed: false, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 20),
//        .init(RewardText: "25% Off Next Haircut", RewardRedeemed: true, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 18),
//        .init(RewardText: "45% Off Next Haircut", RewardRedeemed: true, rewardPhoto: "crown_kings_main_photo", costOfReward: 30)
//    ]
    

    

    @EnvironmentObject private var rewardsViewModel: RewardViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject private var loyaltyViewModel: LoyaltyViewModel
    
    @State var rewards: [Reward] = []
    
    func getRewards() async throws -> [Reward]{
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let snapshot = try await db.collection("redeemRewards").getDocuments()
        let rewards = snapshot.documents.compactMap{try? $0.data(as: Reward.self)}
        
        return rewards
    }
   
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid (columns: [
                    GridItem(.flexible()),
                    GridItem(.flexible()),
                ], spacing: 16, content:{
                    ForEach(rewardsViewModel.rewards, id: \.self) { reward in
                        RewardsCardView(rewardPhoto:reward.rewardPhoto, rewardText: reward.rewardText, rewardRedeemed: reward.rewardRedeemed, costOfReward: reward.costOfReward)
                            .environmentObject(rewardsViewModel)
                            .environmentObject(loyaltyViewModel)
                        
                    }
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                Task{
                    do {
                        let newRewards = try await getRewards()
                        rewards.append(contentsOf: newRewards)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error Fetching rewards: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Rewards")
        }
    }
}

//#Preview {
//    RewardsView()
//}

struct Reward: Identifiable, Codable,Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let rewardText: String
    let rewardRedeemed: Bool
    let rewardPhoto: String
    let costOfReward: CGFloat
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let userId: String
    let remainingPoints: CGFloat
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Reward, rhs: Reward) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

Am I possibly misunderstanding how a view is constructed at runtime?
Thanks for the help, and consideration.

Use task not onappear and get rid of Task. Also get rid of the hash and == implementations. You are quite literally telling SwiftUI don’t reload unless the id changes. You should also always inject environmentObject on the Stack on in it.

also remove the view models, thats what the View structs are for

As @lorem ipsum commented, there would be many places that can be improved but the main reason your code doesn't work is that you're trying to display viewModel.rewards but the fetched data is stored in rewards in the view.
So, try replace
ForEach(rewardsViewModel.rewards, id: \.self) { reward in

with
ForEach(rewards, id: \.self) { reward in


Removed everything  @lorem ipsum and made the change you suggested...but the issue remains.

@JoelCarter Just to confirm, are you succeeding in fetching the data from Firestore? (i.e. no error and no empty result)

After banging my head on this for hours, I realized (after taking a break) that I had spelled the collection name wrong in my call. So in fact, your answer was correct @Toru
